# Why does "w" in fopen here not create a new file?

Tags: c, file

The program always ends up exiting. I seem to be running in to this problem frequently and I think I somehow previously fixed it but I'm not sure how. Why does it not create a file?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void){
    FILE *fp;
    int c;

    char file_w[100];
    char string[100];
    printf("Enter filename\n");
    fgets(file_w, 100, stdin);
    fp = fopen(file_w, "w");
    if (fp == NULL){
        printf("Can't open file\n");
        exit(0);
    }   
    printf("Enter a string");
    fgets(string, 100, stdin);
    for(c = 0; c <= sizeof(string); c++)
    {
        fprintf(fp, "%s\n", string);
    }

    printf("file written");
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please update your post or add an answer if you found what the problem was. BTW: how was your exam? :)

Answer (score 3):

Try to print the name of the file you have entered:

```
printf("%s\n", file_w);
```

just after the line you get file_w, just to be sure to enter what you want. I same cases the terminal could be wrongly configured.

Try to enter an absolute name path, if your computer is a Linux or Unix:

```
/tmp/newfile.txt
```

If your computer is Windows... Well try to see if  C:\temp\ exist (or create it) and then enter:

```
C:\temp\newfile.txt
```

In any case, remember that you can specify an absolute path, and not only the file name. So double check if you have the rights (i.e. the permissions) to write into the directory where the file should be written.

In case you want check the error and have a better description of the problem try to use the following lines instead of your code, just under the fopen

```
  if( fp == NULL ) {
        // Error, as expected.
        perror( "Error opening file" );
        printf( "Error code opening file: %d\n", errno );
        printf( "Error opening file: %s\n", strerror( errno ) );
        exit(-1);
  }
```

strerror it is a wonderful function just because return you a description of the problem instead of an error code.

Comment: I'm getting a error opening file: Invalid argument! Need to get to the bottom of this asap. Exam in an hour! printf confirms that the name is fine.

Comment: I have go in office within 20'. Then try to print the filename first. Be sure you enter only plain text, no strange characters like ?*+

Comment: Yeah, no strange characters the name is fine!

Comment: Just to be sure... Have you tried to add the strerror function I suggested you?

Comment: I did strreror returned : invalid argument

Comment: Have you added #include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
On top of your source code? May be the error is related to errno that is not correctly defined since it is missing the include

Comment: I'm so sorry I have to go. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I bet the problem is "invisible character after actual name from fgets()". I'll let you figure out exactly what that character is, where it comes from and how to fix it, as "struggling to solve a problem" is part of the learning process when it comes to programming. If it was easy, everyone could do it.

Comment: Got 20 mins till an exam if you could figure it out i would be in dept :P

Comment: Don't worry, you'll get it. Try printing (with %d) every character in your string that is the filename... (try with a short name!)

Comment: Hmm, I can create files whose names end with a newline just fine. Is that forbidden on Windows, or what could be the problem?

Comment: Yes, windows doesn't like any whitespace other than 0x20 (possibly nbsp, 0xA0 as well, have never tried, and I'm on a Linux machine. I have seen this before.

Answer (score 0):

If the return value of `fopen` is NULL it means some error occurred. I suggest you look into the `errno` global to see what error has occurred to help you debug why it's not opening the file.

The `w` flag does the following:

> write: Create an empty file for output operations. If a file with the same name already exists, its contents are discarded and the file is treated as a new empty file.

So it should create a file when none exists, or when it does exist, overwrite its content.

If it does not do that, you have another problem, but from the little information you've given, it's hard to tell what it is.

Comment: What other info could I give?

Comment: Should. Admin account. Had a similar program working before hand!

Comment: So have you gone through it with a debugger, and looked what happens? Also check the contents of `errno` as I suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I tried as a name of file the following:

C:\\temp\\test_file.txt

or

fopen("C:\\temp\\employees.txt", "w");

and it works fine, without errors (I made it in Windows 10. GCC win32, Version: 6.3.0).

I think that you have to use an absolute path to create the file.

Answer (score -2):

use gets() instead of fgets()...it will work

.
.
gets(file_w);
.
.

Comment: [`gets()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/gets) is an unsafe function that has been removed from the C standard since C11. You should not encourage people to use it, instead use `fgets()` (or [`getline()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/experimental/dynamic/getline) if possible), and use any trailing newline manually.